# Basic inheritance - too verbose?

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

I'm looking for a programmatically smarter way to inherit here. I'm very new to the world of programming so it's more of methodology I'm looking for here. Is this the right way to inherit?

The base class in this case has a large constructor. Having to call `base(w, x, y, z)` in each inherited class looks incredibly verbose. Quite frankly, it looks like lazy or bad code.

```
public class DataStudioGear : DataItem  {
    string name;

    int moneyValue;
    int compression;
    int wideness;
    int wowFactor;

    public DataStudioGear(string name, int value, int comp, int wide, int wow) {
        this.name = name;
        moneyValue = value;
        compression = comp;
        wideness = wide;
        wowFactor = wow;
    }
}
```

So now any class that inherits from this has to of course, pass those variables along to the constructor. That leaves me with a bunch of classes that look like this:

```
public class Console : DataStudioGear {
    public Console(string name, int value, int comp, int wide, int wow) : base(name, value, comp, wide, wow) {

    }
}

public class Compressor : DataStudioGear {
    public Compressor(string name, int value, int comp, int wide, int wow) : base(name, value, comp, wide, wow) {

    }
}
```

These constructors are huge. Although I'm very new to programming in general, it just looks like bad code.

Is there a better solution for what I'm trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Your code is correct, afaik there isn't a much better way to write it, though I do agree with you that it looks clunky

Comment: your code is fine.  If a class inherits another class, it has to be able to fully construct its base when it itself is constructed.  So it makes sense that if the base constructor requires 5 parameters, your class will need to send it 5 parameters.  If it needs them all at runtime, then it will need a constructor with all those parameters as well.

Comment: One thing to also note is that if the constructor takes in parameters that can be supplied with a default value based on the derived type, you can hard-code the value in `base` constructor and omit it from your derived constructor.

Comment: If some of these properties are ones that aren't always needed and the object can function without them, then you can remove them from the constructor and set them with object instantiation:
`new Foo(x, y) { ZProperty = z};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the factory pattern. The below code uses a static generic method in the base class to generate a subclass while populating the property values.

```
public class DataStudioGear : DataItem
{
    string _name;
    private int _moneyValue;
    int _compression;
    int _wideness;
    int _wowFactor;

    public static T DataTestFactory<T>(string name, int value, int comp, int wide, int wow)
        where T : DataStudioGear, new()
    {
        return new T { _name = name, _moneyValue = value, _compression = comp, _wideness = wide, _wowFactor = wow};
    }
}

public class Console : DataStudioGear { }

public class Compressor : DataStudioGear { }

[TestMethod]
public void TestDataItemFactory()
{
    Console console = DataStudioGear.DataTestFactory<Console>("test", 1, 1, 1, 1);
    Compressor compressor = DataStudioGear.DataTestFactory<Compressor>("test", 1, 1, 1, 1);
}
```

Comment: That's the one my friend! You're amazing! I almost asked if generics were the answer as I suspected they could be of use here!

Comment: Oh hey, which namespace are you using for that fancy unit test?

Comment: Your suspicions were correct. Glad to help! I'm using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting. This can just as easily be swapped with NUnit, just change TestMethod to Test.